# How to mock browser requests based on har files?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, mocking, har

I've exported a har file of my application. Now I would like to reuse it when the server is crashed (it's quite often issue). I was looking for an application that could mock http requests and send the response based on already recorded .har file but could find only Fiddler that is not free anymore. I tried to import har file in the dev console but I need to refresh the page and then the import dissapears. Maybe there's a way to keep the import persistant?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like https://github.com/peterknezek/har-to-mocks is what you need. It will create the mocks which are used by https://github.com/muratcorlu/connect-api-mocker.

Comment: And if you want a .NET version I created this one a few years ago:
https://github.com/mcm-ham/har-mock-server